# Looking for JsonParser dependency

Tags: java, json

I have worked out that JsonParser is in javax.json.stream but i have no idea where i can get a hold of it. Can anyone help me?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/package-summary.html

That's the library i am looking for.

I have tried looking at the maven repositories and found something similar called `javax.json-api` but it does not contain JsonParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven, you can add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

you can also download the artefact manually here

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar

For Gradle, use

```
compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
```

The site https://mvnrepository.com shows you the different dependencies for different build systems.

Please note that this is only one possible dependency. You can certainly find smaller dependencies, which only contain the classes you want. Simply search for it on google or mavencentral.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Json-simple, use the below maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1